# Concurrency and Networking in Flex and Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, concurrency

I am interested in making a RIA in Flex that will communicate with my server. The application will be downloading and uploading very often. It will need to be able to download hundreds of images over the course of its runtime.

However, I have read that Flash does not support threading. Would this be a major problem if I want the UI to run smoothly while the application downloads and uploads in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash uses a separate thread for networking.  All I/O is asynchronous so the UI doesn't block while communicating with the network.